# Laravel Sanctum tokenCan method on User model returns false despite correct ability

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel Sanctum in my Laravel 8 project, I'm building a controller which will allow other Laravel projects to authenticate and check the abilities of a token, to do this I'm finding a token using the `findToken` method, grabbing the `tokenable_id` (this is the user id) and then looking up this user based on the `User` model.

I'm then storing this in a variable and checking the abilities with `tokenCan` but it's always returning false despite my token having the correct abilities, what am I missing from this method?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;
use App\Models\User;

class HubController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new AccountController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('throttle:30,1');
    }

    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'token' => 'required|string',
            'ability' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "It looks like you've missed something.",
                'errors' => $validator->messages()
            ], 400);
        }

        $token = PersonalAccessToken::findToken($request->input('token'));

        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Token not found or is invalid"
            ], 404);
        }

        $user = User::find($token->tokenable_id);

        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "User not found or is invalid"
            ], 404);
        }

        // $user->tokenCan('reports:view') always returning false
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $user->tokenCan('reports:view'),
            'message' => "You don't have the correct permissions to perform this action."
        ], 401);

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the token creation code to the question to better debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can get $user with `$request->user()`.
or use `$request->user()->tokenCan('reports:view')`